# Ubuntu Deadlock, 1000s of Zombie Processes

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS on multiple hosts.

When I'm logging into my servers, I'm greeted with the following error messages on all servers:

```
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

`ps aux` is showing thousands of the following entries

```
...
root     32725  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z+   Nov22   0:00 [dig] <defunct>
root     32726  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z+   Nov21   0:00 [dig] <defunct>
root     32727  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z+   Nov21   0:00 [dig] <defunct>
root     32728  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z+   Nov22   0:00 [dig] <defunct>
root     32766  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z+   Nov21   0:00 [dig] <defunct>
root     32767  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/1    Z+   Nov21   0:00 [dig] <defunct>
...
```

I couldn't find ANY issues in `/var/logs`

What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are greeted with

```
 -bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

is easy to **guess**: you simply have too many running processes. You say you have thousands of defunct `dig` processes, this nearly certainly will exceed the max number of processes you are allowed to own. To make sure that this is correct, issue

```
 ulimit -a
```

where most likely you will find a line like

```
 max user processes              (-u) 46563
```

and, if this number is smaller than the number of defunct processes, there you go.

It is trickier to establish why you have all of those processes. They look like repeated failures to call a DNS server, but this requires something more fundamental than just a network disconnection. Here, for lack of relevant data, I can only offer an educated guess: are you or were you ever on an Ipv6 connection?